# Cows and pigs with osteoporosis?

Tags: pig, cows

What can be done to help a cow that had osteoporosis? Do pigs get osteoporosis as well? What can be done to help a pig with osteoporosis?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably treatment would be similar to humans -- calcium, vitamin D, certain prescription drugs and hormones.